# как вызвать в html файле функцию обработки prompt`s, находящуюся в .js?

Tags: javascript, html, функции

я пытаюсь оставить в хтмл файле только prompts.
три промпта, в которые вводятся 3 возраста age_1, age_2, age_3.
а текст, который должен вернутся определяется функцией checkAge(), принимающей эти три параметра и находящейся в my.js.

про способ написать в <script src'my.js'> я знаю, но можно впринципе сделать так что бы промпты остались в хтмл файле? или это единственный вариант?
https://github.com/offimpulse/html-js

Comment: На момент полной когда подгрузится html файл, JS файл только начнет загружаться, а ваши функции промты уже будут запущены, и не найдут никаких функций из JS файла, следовательно вам нужно "задержать" исполнение кода пока не будут загружены все файлы.... так вот к чему это я? точно : https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded

Comment: можно в том же файле написать js код в теге <script>